# How to set up pauses with normal distribution in Gatling

Tags: gatling, scala-gatling

How can I set up pauses in Gatling with normal distribution with mean and standard deviation

1. on Simulation level - which will apply to all requests
2. override scenario level pauses with other values for specific requests

I can't exactly figure it out looking at gatling's documentation [Global Pause configuration](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/simulation_setup#global-pause-configuration) and [scenario pauses](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/?highlight=pause#scenario-pause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

In each request you can define a pause (different pause types are available)

```
exec(http("GET /")
.get("/"))
.pause(10,20)
```

Above code will add random(uniform?) pause between 10 and 20 seconds

Then in the simulation level you can define globally that you'd like to use normal distribution e.g.

```
    .inject(
      rampUsers(1)
        .during(1)
    )
    .pauses(normalPausesWithStdDevDuration(5))
```

Above configuration will take pause set up on request level as a mean value and use std deviation 5s to chose final pause value